# Estimating the number of bottles in a set

Tags: extreme-value

Say a distillery released a limited edition set of whiskey bottles but do not say how many have been released... If the bottles are individually uniquely numbered (bottle No.55, for example), is it possible to estimate the total number of bottles from a sample of bottle numbers?

Comment: I believe this is just an alternative way of framing the German Tank Problem, replacing "tanks" with whiskey bottles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem If you feel that this problem is distinct in some statistically important way, please edit to clarify.